App pool recycle because of file change on idle-timeout
When my application in IIS reaches idle-timeout (20 by default) I have 2 events in the same second:

A worker process with process id "123" serving application pool "SomePool" was shutdown due to inactivity.

Application was recycled after detecting file change in application directory.


I can not understand why I receive the second message event. I tried to forbid any write permissions for all users on app directory but I still receive this event on idle-timeout. I have this problem only for net-core apps. Have anyone any thoughts why I receive message about app pool recycling because of file change?

Try using Process Monitor to monitor activity for yourself.

You can also write your own monitoring program to track the relationship between file changes and application pool recycling. You can use the FileSystemWatcher class provided by the .NET framework to monitor file changes in the IIS directory.
